# No module named 'pip._internal'; 'pip' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package, command-prompt

I am new to using python, and am wanting to be able to install packages for python using pip. I am having trouble running pip on my windows computer. When typing in "pip --version" into command prompt I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'; 'pip' is not a package
```

I have added the scripts folder to the PATH environment variable as shown on the picture in this link 
[Environment variables photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXiFz.png)
(Stack overflow does not allow embedded pictures if you are new)

This is the contents of my scripts directory where pip is present:

```
Directory of C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts

[.]                    [..]                   easy_install-3.7.exe
easy_install.exe       pip-script.py          pip.exe
pip.exe.manifest       pip3                   pip3-script.py
pip3.7-script.py       pip3.7.exe             pip3.7.exe.manifest
pip3.exe               pip3.exe.manifest      wheel.exe
```

Any help on this would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Force a reinstall of pip:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall
```

For windows you may have to `choco install curl` or set PATH to where python3 is located

Answer (score 0):

In cmd try using

`py -3.6 -m pip install pygmae`

replace 3.6 with your version of python and add -32 fot 32 bit version

```
py -3.6-32 pip install pygame
```

replace pygame with the module you want to install

this works for most people using python on windows also reboot your pc after adding system variable path

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this in cmd and still get:
C:\WINDOWS\System32>py -3.7-32 -m pip install pygame
Collecting install
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for install

Comment: ok this means that your pip is working ok but I think pygame doesn't have a version for python 3.7 try using some other library that you know supports python 3.7 32 bit version such as numpy or cv2 let me know what happens cuz I have another way to install libraries using brute force on windows

Comment: This is the result I currently get when entering C:\WINDOWS\System32>py -3.7-32 pip install numpy
(null): can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: try uninstalling python 3.7 and then reinstalling the latest version then try again.